# How to use the edit_path in Rails for testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

I am setting up automatic testing for my Rails application. I am working on my controller test and I am getting an unrecognized id error. I know the edit route works for the app right now because I can go to the actual link(/adjusters/3293/edit), but I cannot get my test to past.

```
 def setup
    @adjuster = Adjuster.new(adjuster_name: "TestLastName", address_1: "4511 W 200 S", id: 1)
 end

 test "should get edit" do
   get edit_adjuster_path(@adjuster)
   assert_response :success
 end
```

When I rake my routes the edit route shows.

```
edit_adjuster GET    /adjusters/:id/edit(.:format) adjusters#edit
```

Here is the error I am receiving

```
Couldn't find Adjuster with 'id'=1
```

My show route works though

```
test "should get show" do
  get adjusters_path(@adjuster)
  assert_response :success
end
```

Comment: If you create the object instead of just instantiating it with 'new' does it work?

Comment: That worked! Thanks bkunzi